# How to display grouped bar chart using chart.js?

Tags: angular-material, chart.js

I am currently building a grouped bar chart, with two different datasets using chart.js. The code in the component.js file is as follows:

```
createChart(){
    var lbls = ['Selling', 'Cost', 'Gross'];
    var curYearData = [2345, 1234, 1111];
    var preYearData = [3456, 2345, 1111];

    var ctx = document.getElementById(‘barChart') as HTMLCanvasElement;
    var barChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: lbls,
        datasets: [
        {
          label: ‘2020',
          data: curYearData,
          backgroundColor: 'blue',
        },
        {
          label: ‘2019',
          data: preYearData,
          backgroundColor: 'red',
        }]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

However, I see no data displayed and instead I get an empty screen. How to create a grouped bar chart in chart.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in your code.

First you don't correctly retrieve the 2D-Context.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('barChart').getContext('2d');
```

Further you have some strange apostrophes that need to be changed.

Please have a look at your amended code below.

```js
var lbls = ['Selling', 'Cost', 'Gross'];
var curYearData = [2345, 1234, 1111];
var preYearData = [3456, 2345, 1111];

var ctx = document.getElementById('barChart').getContext('2d');
var barChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: lbls,
    datasets: [{
        label: '2020',
        data: curYearData,
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
      },
      {
        label: '2019',
        data: preYearData,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="barChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: When I try to retrieve the 2D-context, I get the following error: `Property 'getContext' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.ts(2339).` Removing the “as HTMLCanvasElement” gives me another error in the chart declaration saying, `Argument of type 'HTMLElement' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | CanvasRenderingContext2D | HTMLCanvasElement | ArrayLike<CanvasRenderingContext2D | HTMLCanvasElement>'.
  Type 'HTMLElement' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLCanvasElement': height, width, getContext, toBlob, and 2 more.`

Comment: @Nooh Ahamad: can you make a StackBlitz?